# OpenMP: Share single-threaded and multi-threaded implementations of the same algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm working in a code base where several algorithms are implemented twice: once with a `#pragma omp parallel` in just the right place, and once without. The functions are named things like `AlgorithmMT()` and `AlgorithmST()`.

Simplified example:

```cpp
/// Multi-threaded algorithm
std::vector<double>
AlgorithmMT(int n)
{
    std::vector<double> result(n);
    std::itoa(result.begin(), result.end(), 1.0);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result[i] = i / result[i];
    }
    return result;
}

/// Single-threaded algorithm
std::vector<double>
AlgorithmST(int n)
{
    std::vector<double> result(n);
    std::itoa(result.begin(), result.end(), 1.0);
// NOTE: there is no #pragma here
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result[i] = i / result[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Assuming that I need to preserve two separate functions (higher level code can't be changed), and that users should be allowed to select between them at run time, how can I get the two functions to share a common implementation?

I realize that the algorithm is a bit nonsensical and could be implemented without a read dependency on `result` inside the loop. Please just assume this is the required structure of the algorithm. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clean way is to use the `if` clause of `parallel` constructs, e.g.:

```
bool is_parallel = ...;
#pragma omp parallel for if (is_parallel)
```

This is evaluated at run-time and per definition has the same effect of spawning a single thread.

This runtime distinction isn't exactly the same as omitting the `pragma`, the compiler may optimize the code differently. While I wouldn't worry too much, you should observe your performance. Just compile the application without `-fopenmp` and compare performance with dynamically disabled parallelism. *If* there is a discrepancy, you may have to resort to redundant code or help the compiler in some way. Note that the performance may vary among compilers.

Comment: This looks brilliant. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `omp_set_num_threads` from the OpenMP runtime API to limit the thread count to one before your parallel section, then restore it after the section.

*Warning:* If there's an other parallel thread running already, then `omp_set_num_threads` will affect the parallel sections there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since `#pragma` is preprocessor you cannot do a whole lot sadly.
You could create `algorithm.cpp.part` with your function inside but `%parallel%` in place of `#pragma omp for` and then, at compile time, replace the text with something like this in a makefile:

```
sed '/%parallel%/c\#pragma omp parallel'  algorithm.cpp.part > algorithm_mt.cpp
sed '/%parallel%/c\ '  algorithm.cpp.part > algorithm_st.cpp
```

If you have lots of functions like this it could scale relatively well with a good makefile rule.

Or if you are compiling for Windows you could use the concurrency runtime, it avoids using `#pragma`, which could be useful in your situation.

(don't be too harsh with this answer, I'm writing this on my phone)

Comment: You can change the max number of threads at runtime, effectively making the code single threaded.

Comment: But it could result in issues if multiple threads want a different setting. Anyways, both of our answers are hacks and could results into bigger issues really.